# How to insert JavaScript Data into mysql database?

Tags: php, javascript

The Data i am trying to insert is a blob or a file
This is for a school project and the lecturer said to insert it into the database for now.

This is what i have right now

```
function stop() {
  cancelAnimationFrame(rafId);
  endTime = Date.now();
  $('#stop-me').disabled = true;
  document.title = ORIGINAL_DOC_TITLE;

  toggleActivateRecordButton();

  console.log('frames captured: ' + frames.length + ' => ' +
              ((endTime - startTime) / 1000) + 's video');

  embedVideoPreview();
};

function embedVideoPreview(opt_url) {
  var url = opt_url || null;
  var video = $('#video-preview video') || null;
  var downloadLink = $('#video-preview a[download]') || null;

  if (!video) {
    video = document.createElement('video');
    video.autoplay = true;
    video.controls = true;
    video.loop = true;
    //video.style.position = 'absolute';
    //video.style.top = '70px';
    //video.style.left = '10px';
    video.style.width = canvas.width + 'px';
    video.style.height = canvas.height + 'px';
    $('#video-preview').appendChild(video);

    downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    downloadLink.download = 'capture.webm';
    downloadLink.textContent = '[ download video ]';
    downloadLink.title = 'Download your .webm video';
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.appendChild(downloadLink);

    $('#video-preview').appendChild(p);

  } else {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(video.src);
  }

  if (!url) {
    var webmBlob = Whammy.fromImageArray(frames, 1000 / 60);
    url = window.URL.createObjectURL(webmBlob);
  }

  video.src = url;
  downloadLink.href = url;
```

And this is how i am inserting it into the database from the same page i am also not to sure on where the video blob is also created.

```
  <?php
    require("connect.php");
    $namey = video;
    $up = mysql_query("INSERT INTO video VALUES ($namey)");
  ?>
```

Comment: How are you getting the javascript data back to the server? AJAX? or is this your question?

Comment: I dont know if this is a real question.. But did i read correctly that you're storing films in SQL for school ? And then writing a question online about it. Interesting youth of this generation.

Comment: I agree, the video data not something that should be stored in a SQL database. A much better approach would be to upload the file to a folder on the system, then save the URL to the file in the database, then you can use that URL in your `<video>` element or however you are using it.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @SnareChops How Would i Go about doing that?

Comment: If the below answer presented a solution to your question, please accept the answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer. This will help future users searching for an answer to the same question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so say you have an input for a user to upload a video...

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="VideoToUpload" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Video" />
</form>
```

Then in your new `upload.php` you will want to process and save the file

```
$allowedExts = array("mp4", "mov");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["VideoToUpload"]["name"]));
if (($_FILES["VideoToUpload"]["type"] == "video/mp4") || ($_FILES["VideoToUpload"]["type"] == "video/quicktime")):
    if($_FILES["VideoToUpload"]["error"] > 0):
        echo "Error: " . $_Files["VideoToUpload"]["error"];
    else:
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["VideoToUpload"]["tmp_name"], dirname(__FILE__) . "/FolderWhereIWantMyVideoSaved/" . $_FILES["VideoToUpload"]["name"]);
    endif;
endif;
$VideoURL = "http://domain/and/path/to/FolderWhereIWantMyVideoSaved/" . $_FILES["VideoToUpload"];
$mysqli = new mysqli('ip.of.data.base', 'DatabaseName', 'Password', 'Username');    
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Videos (Name, Type, URL) VALUES (?,?,?)") or die ($mysqli->error);
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $_FILES["VideoToUpload"]["name"],$_FILES["VideoToUpload"]["type"], $VideoURL);
$stmt->execute() or die ($mysqli->error);
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

Now the file is saved on the server, and the URL to that is in the database. So to display the video all you would then do is.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('ip.of.data.base', 'DatabaseName', 'Password', 'Username');    
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Name, Type, URL FROM Videos WHERE ID=?") or die ($mysqli->error);
$stmt->execute() or die($mysqli->error);
$stmt->bind_result($Name, $Type, $URL);
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->fetch();
...
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="<?= $URL ?>" type="<?= $Type ?>">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
...
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
```